# How to make a for loop go to the next line when printing the result

Tags: java

So I am trying to get the sentence "Never give up.  Today is hard, tomorrow will be worse, but the day after tomorrow will be sunshine!" to delete all special characters and then print out like this:

Never

give

up

Today

is

hard

tomorrow

will

be

worse

but

the

day

after

tomorrow

will

be

sunshine

Currently it is printing:

NevergiveupTodayishardtomorrowwillbeworsebutthedayaftertomorrowwillbesunshine

I have tried adding in a System.out.println(); statement but it is not working as I anticipated when alongside the return statement.

```
String split(String s){

    String tmp = "";

    for(i=0; i<s.length(); i++)

        if(s.charAt(i)>64 && s.charAt(i)<=122){

            tmp = tmp+s.charAt(i);

        }

    return tmp;


}
```

Comment: You need to add some newline (`'\n'`) characters in the string you're building.

Comment: tmp = tmp+s.charAt(i)+"\n";

Comment: When adding that in it prints each individual character and then goes to the next line. How am I supposed to keep each full word and the skip to the next line?

Comment: `Arrays.stream("Never give up. Today is hard, tomorrow will be worse, but the day after tomorrow will be sunshine!".split("\\s+")).map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\W", "")).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't putting a newline between the lines. You want to append '\n' to each line in order for it to print how you expect it:

```
String split(String s){

    String tmp = "";

    for(i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {

        if(s.charAt(i)>64 && s.charAt(i)<=122){

            tmp = tmp+s.charAt(i);

        }

        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            tmp = tmp+"\n";
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Note: There are much easier ways to do this, but my update simply shows how to alter your current solution to work as you expect.

As pointed out by Zabuza, if you want to be sure this prints correctly in any OS, you can use `System.lineSeparator()` in place of `"\n"`

Comment: Please suggest platform independent solutions. Use `System.lineSeparator()` instead.

Comment: Using your solution it will print each character on new line. It's not what is requested.

Comment: Yep. You are correct. I updated my answer to append a newline anytime a space character is encountered

Comment: @Troncoso you might want to include the other if statement in the for loop .

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize the original code didn't have brackets. Fixed